# mod_rewrite redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my directory structure:

http://files.example.com/files/

All of the files reside in the files/ directory

I want the URL to be http://files.example.com/somefile.txt even though somefile.txt is in the files/ directory.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ files/$1
```

If somebody requests http://files.example.com/somefile.txt and somefile.txt is in the files/ directory, everything works ok.

However, if somefile.txt does not exist, it results in an internal server error (500), too many redirects.

How can I send the user to a 404 page if the specified file does not exist?

example: going to http://files.example.com/a-file-that-does-not-exist.txt
will redirect to a custom 404 page rather than too many redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ files/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /files/$1 [L]
```

If the file doesn't exist in /files/, let the rewrite take care of the 404, meaning you don't need the !-d and !-f checks.

Comment: Are you are missing the TestString e.g. `%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond files/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !^files/(.*)$ files/$1
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but now it gives me a 404 for _every_ file requested, even if it _does_ exist in the directory. bizarre!

Comment: This only works if the user goes to http://files.example.com/files/somefile.txt  anyway to get that files directory out of the url?

Comment: You must use `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/%{REQUEST_URI} -f` instead. `-f` requires a full path, not a url. Also %{REQUEST_FILENAME} contains a full path. So for example the url `/somefile.txt` will result in `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` being `/var/www/domain/somefile.txt`, so your rule checkes if the file `/files/var/www/domain/somefile.txt` exitst. Which never does.